React child component causes grid items to be placed in next row in horizontally-expandable grid before the previous row is filled
Bear with me, as the problem is difficult to describe clearly.
I have an app that lists "items" in a grid. This grid is only large enough to hold a single item at first, but it expands with each new item up to five items, at which point new items are added to the next row. When the second row reaches five items, the next one is placed on row 3.
I originally had a static "add item" button at the top of the page, but I decide it made more sense practically and aesthetically to have the add button be the last "item" in the grid such that when you hit the add button, it is replaced by a new item. This seemed more intuitive as the add button sits where you would be adding another item.
I achieved this using child components. Each grid item component is just a div container set to the proper width and height to fill a single grid component, and it takes in a child component which can be either an item in the grid or the add button.
Everything was working fine before using this child component scheme - and in fact still works fine with "items" as child components of the "item container" components. However, when I add an "item container" with an add button as a child component, that add button gets placed on a new row despite the previous row not being filled with 5 items.

What is even stranger is when I put in some temporary code to make the add button a middle item in the list with more regular items coming after, the add button will appear in the proper space in the current row - but all items after will start on the next row!

There's a lot of code involved, so I'm hoping somebody might have an idea of a general issue in the way somebody might try to implement this that would cause this result. Even so, I'll do my best to strip it down to the most relevant code so you've got some idea of what I'm doing.
App.tsx:
    type AddButtonProps = {
  onAddCoinSlot: () => void;
}

type CoinsListItemProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode,
  bordered?: boolean
}

const AddButton = function (props: AddButtonProps) {
  return(
    <>
      <input type="button" onClick = {props.onAddCoinSlot} value="+" id="add-button"></input>
    </>
  )
}

const CoinsListItem = (props: CoinsListItemProps) => {
  let borderedClassName = props.bordered ? " bordered" : "";
  return(
    <div className={"coin-slot" + borderedClassName}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}
  let coinList = coinsDataWithAddButton.map((coin, index) => {
    if(coin !== null){
      return(
        <CoinsListItem bordered={true}>
          <CoinSlot 
            id={index}
            coinTicker={coin.ticker}
            addressEntryIsOpen={coin.addressEntryIsOpen}
            availableCoins={availableCoins}
            coinImage={coin.image}
            address={coin.address}
            addressIsValid={coin.addressIsValid}
            isCustom={coin.rank === -1 ? true : false}
            onChangeCoin={onChangeCoin}
            onChangeAddress={onChangeAddress}
            onChangeLogo={onChangeLogo}
            onChangeTicker={onChangeTicker}
            onRemoveCoinSlot={onRemoveCoinSlot}
            toggleAddressEntryArea={onToggleAddressEntry}
            moveCoinSlot={moveCoinSlot}
            lines={coin.lines}
          />
        </CoinsListItem>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <CoinsListItem>
          <AddButton onAddCoinSlot={onAddCoinSlot}/>
        </CoinsListItem>
      )
    }
  })

 return (

    <div className="App">
      <div className="debug">
      </div>
      <div className="app-box">
        <h1>Cryptowidget Builder</h1>
        <div className="coin-list-container">
          <AddButton onAddCoinSlot={onAddCoinSlot}/>
          <div className="coin-list">
            {coinList}
          </div>
        </div>
        <button onClick={onGenerateQrs} value="Get widget" disabled={generationIsDisabled}>Get widget</button>
        <button onClick={makeAllAddressesValid} value="Make addresses valid (for testing)">Make Addresses Valid</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

CoinSlot.tsx:
    return(
    <>
        <input type="button" className="remove-button" onClick = {onRemoveCoinSlot} value="X"></input>
        <img src={props.coinImage} id="background-image" alt="coin"></img>
        <div className="coin-slot-grid">
            <div className="move-button-container">
                <button className="move-button" onClick={moveCoinSlotLeft}>{"<"}</button>
            </div>
            <div className="coin-slot-options">
                <div className="select-area">
                    <select value={props.coinTicker || ""} className = "dropdown-menu" onChange={onChangeCoin}>
                        {coinOptions}
                    </select>
                </div>

                {addressEntryElement}
                <div className={customCoinOptionsClassName}>
                    <input type="text" onChange={onChangeTicker} value={props.customTicker} className="custom-ticker-entry" placeholder="ticker"></input>
                    <input type="file" id={"logo-chooser-" + props.id.toString()} className="logo-chooser" onChange={onChangeLogo} ></input>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="move-button-container">
                <button className="move-button" onClick={moveCoinSlotRight}>{">"}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
)

